# SQL stored procedure where database to query is parameter

Tags: sql, ms-access, stored-procedures, parameters

I am working with Microsoft Access (not SQL server) and have written a stored procedure (Query) as shown below in SQL.

This procedure works but it relies on a hard coded path to the database from which to pull (SELECT) the data.

To make the query more useful I want to pass the database to SELECT from as a parameter to the query - how does one do this?

```
INSERT INTO Part_Batteries ( ItemCode, Size, Voltage )
SELECT tblBatteries.ItemCode, tblBatteries.SizeAH, tblBatteries.Voltage
FROM tblBatteries IN 'C:\Databases\DeviceDatabases\UKDevices.mdb';
```

I.e. I want to replace the line

```
FROM tblBatteries IN 'C:\Databases\DeviceDatabases\UKDevices.mdb';
```

with something like this

```
FROM tblBatteries IN @DB
```

Currently I am testing the procedures by either clicking on them in Access or by calling them from a VB module.

When I am satisfied they work I will call them as required from the main application that will be built using C#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried if that worked? Looks like it should work, the path is a string and most strings can easily be replaced by a variable.

Comment: if you are using the VB environment in MS Access to create the SP check if this helps > http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=202116

Comment: "I am working with Microsoft Access and SQL and..." -- Are you working with SQL Server? At least one answer so far thinks you are. I am aware the Access Database Engine supports `CREATE PROCEDURE` syntax when in ANSI-92 Query Mode but many folk take exception when you call the resulting database object a 'stored procedure'. Regardless, I'm almost sure that the path to the .mdb file cannot be paramterized in Access Database Engine SQL.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? You do realize that using a path name in the SQL means that the path name must be able to be resolved FROM the server side. If you move the client application off of the same machine that SQL server is running on then when users executes the SP as it now they will be pulling data from the computer that is running the instance of SQL server and NOT the client computer that is calling this code! If this is going to be single user all the time then you be fine, but in the case of multi-user then the path name to the mdb file CAN NOT be on the client computer.

Comment: Ah, perhaps no sql server is involved as onedaywhen points out. If that is the case, then my sql server comments don't apply. On the other hand, I also see little advantage to using JET declared store procedure if that is the case. However, I should point out that access 2010 does in fact have both table triggers and stored procedures, but they do are not based on sql.

Comment: SQL Server is not used. The database will only ever be used by one user at a time. It is delivered with a .NET application. I'm in the process of redesigning a legacy Access DB. The new DB needs to be in Access also. I'm new to SQL and database design but was under the impression that using stored procedures (queries) would provide better performance and like that it keeps the queries defined in the same place as the data; compared to constructing the queries in the application itself.

Comment: You're using terminology in a way that is confusing the issue. The term "stored procedure" is something that experienced Access developers are accustomed for using only server-side code, e.g., T-SQL scripts in SQL Server. While technically a saved DML QueryDef in Access (or a parameterized SQL SELECT or DML statement) can be seen as being like a stored procedure without any procedural code, it's really not helpful to call it that.

Comment: The IN portion of the FROM clause cannot be parameterized in Access/Jet/ACE (I don't believe any part of the FROM clause can be parameterized, actually, except perhaps expressions in JOINs). The N in TOP N selects cannot, either. You need to either construct your IN clause dynamically in code, or write your saved QueryDef on the fly each time you need to change the IN clause.

Answer (score 1):

Please read this http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#storedprocedures

I think it is what you are looking for.

Comment: I think OP was asking in the context of MS-Access SPs

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable at the top of your stored proc

```
DECLARE @DB AS string

INSERT INTO Part_Batteries ( ItemCode, Size, Voltage )
SELECT tblBatteries.ItemCode, tblBatteries.SizeAH, tblBatteries.Voltage
FROM tblBatteries IN @DB;
```

Comment: Thanks. Just tried that & I get a SQL syntax error "invalid sql statement expected 'delete' 'insert' 'procedure' 'select' or 'update'"